# Calling Node from Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a total newbie Angular question I guess, but I thought this would be easier than it appears to be.

I've got a simple html form:

```
<div>
    <form ng-submit="processUrls()">
        <label>Urls to Process</label>
        <button class="btn" style="margin-left:15em;">Process</button>
        <br />
        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" wrap="soft" ng-model="process.urls">
</textarea>
        <label>Output:</label>
        <input style="width:25em;" ng-model="output.outputText" />
    </form>
</div>
```

and a simple function:

```
$scope.processUrls = function() {
            $http.get("http://localhost:4355/test1").then(function(response){
                $scope.output.outputText = response.data;
            },function(response){
                alert("data = " + response.data + "\r\nstatus = " + response.status + "\r\nstatusText = " + response.statusText);
                $scope.output.outputText = "Error: " + response.data;
            });
        };
```

It's calling a node service, which is running and writing to the console for each call, so I'm sure it's working and being called. Here it is:

```
// temp route for testing of Angular
server.route({
    method: "GET",
    path: "/test1",
    handler: function(request, reply) {
        return reply("Hello World").code(200);
    }
});
```

But, this doesn't seem to work. All I get back is "Error: null" and my alert tells me virtually nothing. So, I'm wondering if this is related to cross-domain something-or-other, or if I'm just missing something fundamental. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

V

Comment: are they on the same domain, if so try $http.get('/test1')..

Comment: Open up a browser with a debug console (F12) and see what the error message is.

Comment: Duh, I knew to do that. Sorry for being so daft. It's a CORS problem: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:4355/test1. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). I'll add the header and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, on second thought, maybe I don't know how to do that. One thing in my environment is that I'm just loading my index.html file into my browser; it isn't served from a web server. Also, I'm not really sure how to add this header. Does this happen at the node service?

Comment: If you are not going to have CORS in production, just add static files to be served from your node.js app and save yourself time and nerves.

Comment: Good advice vittore. That's what I did - just create a static folder under Node and gave it a dynamic route. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so just to provide an answer here: this was a CORS problem and it was created because I was just loading my angular html file into my browser. By creating a new server route in my node service and a 'static' directory with all of my web files, this problem went away.

I'm using hapijs; the static route looks like this:

```
server.route({
    method: "GET",
    path: "/web/{param*}",
    handler: {
        directory: {
            path: "static"
        }
    }
});
```